# Admob and push notification on same XDK app

Tags: cordova, push-notification, admob, intel-xdk

in xdk there is only cordova admob plugin. And pushmobi is for html5 apps, not for cordova. Is there any way to use these both in same app?

Answer (score 3):

You can find intel-xdk documentation here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-xdk

You can use those two plugins which I'm also maintaining:

- https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova
- https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-push-notifications

To use in your project:

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.google
cordova plugin add com.notifications.push
```

To use admob ads:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitial();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Push notifications are a little bit tricky because they need special configuration, anyway not difficult if you follow the documentation: https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-push-notifications

Comment: Hi @Miquel can I use gcm without any additional service? Because I say see push notification services like pushwoosh are already using gcm. So what is the point of using them when I can use gcm? And thank you these will work for me.

Comment: @zahedae this is client side library, which is a complete library. I'm sorry I'm not really understanding what you mean with additional service: you just need to use this library and your javascript code. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5gf7m1mhz8apg4/pushNotifications.js?dl=0) an example on how your javascript code should be (it's just a piece and may not be fullly functional as it is, as it will require adaption. Also it's angular wrapped, but the main class is javascript and can be 99% reused).

Answer (score 1):

For admob I use this plugin 
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

It works perfectly and very easy to use

Comment: Hi @onereik I see there is admob for cordova and push notification for html 5. But what I am looking for push notification for cordova or admob for html5. So that I can use both of them in same app.